# Using strtotime() and update_post_meta not saving

Tags: metabox, timestamp

I would like to take a date entered in a meta box field, & convert it into a Unix timestamp (dd/mm/yyyy) and save it in the `wp_postmeta` table.  But my code isn't working:

```
function save_custom_meta($post_id) {

    //check permissions
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))
            return $post_id;


    // Convert _date to actual date stamp
     if($field['type'] == 'eventdate') {
     get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_eventdate', true)
        strtotime('_date');
        }

     if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
        update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

What have I got wrong, please? Thank-you for taking an interest!

**UPDATED**

How can I save the date in dd/mm/yyyy format, so that I can then sort  them by date order asc/desc? UNIX timestamp is not appropriate, apparently.

Comment: `strtotime('_date')` cannot work; you have to pass a real date string.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, `dd/mm/yyyy` is _not_ a Unix timestamp.

Comment: @vancoder Thank-you for taking an interest. I would like to store dates entered via a meta box field in dd/mm/yyyy format. How should I do this please? Can you just point me in the right direction? I would then like to sort these dates ( part of a custom post type for events) in desc etc order. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to sort by dates after saving this, you may be better of really saving them as unix timestamp (which is just an int so can be sorted really easy) instead of a formatted date string like dd/mm/yyyy. To sort this datestring you would first need to transform them back to a sortable representation.

I suggest you save it as unix timestamp and just format to your needs on output.

Comment: Your code is rather confused/confusing. What is the `get_post_meta` meant to be doing? Where is `$key` defined? Also, you do not need both `update_post_meta` and `add_post_meta`, as `update_post_meta` will suffice - see the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta).

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82965/21376

Comment: First vancoder is right. Your code is really confusing. Also you don't mention what the initial value looks like. So it's impossible to tell how to transform it into whatever representation. What's inside $value?