# How to compare date in post meta value

Tags: meta-query, date

I have some custom meta fields. Some are date fields but WordPress saves everything as a string, so how can I compare the dates?

```
$meta_query_args = array(
    'relation' => '', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
    array(
        'key'     => 'my_custom_date_field',
        'value'   => '',
        'compare' => '>'
    )
);
$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

I found this, but how can I add some more conditions with dynamic variable / prepared statement?

Comment: Do you have it in the preferred format (YYYYMMDD)? [WP_Query Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters): *"The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the date is stored at the format YYYYMMDD and tested with this format."* - that's a start.

Comment: thanks . i will change it and try . can i use prepared statement with WP_Query ?

Comment: Try: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82965/21376

Comment: @zod Prepared statement such as SQL? Not with WP_Query but you can use [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) just make sure you always use `prepare()` for safety.

Comment: Or: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124163/21376